# Плагин vim-airline отображается не правильно

Tags: vim

После установки `vim-airline` плагина, он выглядит вот так:
[image]

Хотя по идее должен был выглядеть вот так:
[image]

Список всех плагинов:

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'rking/ag.vim'
Plugin 'skwp/greplace.vim'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'StanAngeloff/php.vim'
Plugin 'arnaud-lb/vim-php-namespace'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer'
Plugin 'tobyS/vmustache'
Plugin 'tobyS/pdv'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
```

Часть конфига `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible

syntax enable
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set number
let mapleader = ',' 
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=           
set autowriteall                    
set complete=.,w,b,u                    
set tabstop=8
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

"------------Visuals-------------"
set background=dark
colorscheme material-theme
set t_CO=256                
set guifont=Operator\Mono\ weight=350\ 10
set linespace=10
set guioptions-=e           

set guioptions-=l           
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=R

hi LineNr guibg=bg
set foldcolumn=2
hi foldcolumn guibg=bg

hi vertsplit guifg=bg guibg=bg
```

Использую Ubuntu 16.04, пробовал запускать `gVim` и просто `vim`, так же убирал всё что касается темы и шрифтов, но результат тот же.

Comment: А шрифт с поддержкой powerline symbols или нет?
Попробуйте Input или Iosevka. Или какой-нибудь из пропатченных шрифтов https://github.com/powerline/fonts

Comment: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline#integrating-with-powerline-fonts

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, как оказалось установил их и даже на моем шрифте Operator что-то появилось, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правильно сказал @AlexeyTen нужно было установить [powerline/fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts), хоть моего шрифта не было в их списке, но после выполнения команд:

```
# clone
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
# install
cd fonts
./install.sh
# clean-up a bit
cd ..
rm -rf fonts
```

Плагин стал отображаться лучше, но всё равно не так как хотелось бы, думаю если заменить на поддерживаемый шрифт всё будет нормально.

Теперь панель показывается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно глянуть на https://github.com/piq9117/operator-mono-nerdfont. А в нём же нет кириллицы?

Comment: @AlexeyTen нет, мне она и не нужна, я ей не использую в коде, разве что в комментариях  от других разработчиков встречается

Comment: @AlexeyTen странно, но ничего не изменилось после nerdfont, даже менял на другие шрифты которые были под Powerline сделаны ,вид такой же, возможно сессию обновить надо чтобы шрифты нормально подтянулись, в любом случае так уже лучше